# Can I save memory by writing SQL instead of ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rails-activerecord

Is ActiveRecord beneficial in any way other than its concise, readable syntax? Is it true that ActiveRecord take up more memory than pure SQL? (I'm using PostgreSQL.)

I read in Alexander Dymo's [blog post on Rails performance](https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/performance) that ActiveRecord takes up more memory than pure SQL:

> It's easy to manipulate the data with ActiveRecord. But ActiveRecord
>   is essentially a wrapper on top of your data. If you have a 1G of data
>   in the table, ActiveRecord representation of it will take 2G and, in
>   some cases, more. Yes, in 90% of cases that overhead is justified by
>   extra convenience that you get. But sometimes you don't need it.

I also read in [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) that ActiveRecord is "better":

> If you're used to using raw SQL to find database records, then you
>   will generally find that there are better ways to carry out the same
>   operations in Rails. Active Record insulates you from the need to use
>   SQL in most cases.

I have been experiencing `Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)` on Heroku, so in an effort to solve, have learned about bloat and memory leak. I have identified some ways to improve, including loading ActiveRecord data eagerly, as in `List.joins(:quantities).find(@list_id)`, as well as reducing overall calls to the database. But I am still hungry for memory.

If the benefit of ActiveRecord is only that it is easier to write, then I will write the pure SQL where I can. But I am hoping the SO community can comment on the tradeoffs and fill in any gaps in my understanding, especially if I should think twice before moving away from AR.

Would it be Very Bad to get rid of AR altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to look at the next paragraph in that blog post to get some context:

> One example where you can avoid ActiveRecord's overhead is bulk updates. The code below will neither instantiate any model nor run validations and callbacks.
>
> ```
> Book.where('title LIKE ?', '%Rails%').update_all(author: 'David')
> ```

The author isn't saying that you should use raw SQL to pull data (as a bunch of hashes) into Rails instead of using ActiveRecord to pull data into Rails (as a bunch of models), they're saying that you shouldn't pull a bunch of data out of the data, manipulate it in Rails, and then put it back when you can push all that work right into the database.

Consider the difference between:

```
Book.where('title LIKE ?', '%Rails%').update_all(author: 'David')
```

and

```
Book.where('title LIKE ?', '%Rails%').each do |b|
  b.update(author: 'David')
end
```

The first one simply sends a bit of SQL into the database:

```
update books
set author = 'David'
where title like '%Rails%'
```

and lets the database do all the work. Barely any data moves between the database and your Rails app, your app uses barely any memory for this, and your app does barely any work/CPU for this.

The second one pulls a bunch of rows out of the database, creates a bunch of ActiveRecord models, runs a bunch of Ruby code (create the model, set a value, run validations, ...), then sends a bunch of single row SQL UPDATEs back to the database. This version transfers more data over the network, uses more memory in Rails, and uses more CPU to run more Ruby code.

The message isn't "don't use ActiveRecord", the message is to put your data manipulation logic in the right place rather than dogmatically doing everything in Rails because you heard something about "no logic in the database" somewhere.

---

Memory problems with ActiveRecord usually come from instantiating too many models. If you're saying `Model.all`, you're probably doing it wrong. If you're trying to manipulate more than a couple models at once in Rails, you're probably doing it wrong. ORMs are great for working with individual models, they're terrible for bulk operations.

If you drop down to section 2.2 of that blog post:

> Sometimes the task at hand is better done with other tools. Most commonly it's a database. Why? Because Ruby is bad at processing large data sets. Like, very very bad. Remember, Ruby takes a large memory footprint. So, for example, to process 1G of data you might need 3G and more of memory. It will take several dozen seconds to garbage collect 3G. Good database can process the data in under a second. Let me show a few examples.

and you'll see the blog's author saying the same thing.

Comment: Thank you @mu, this is helpful! I understand the above regarding bulk updates, and that this can cause major memory issues. If I may, a couple of follow-ups. Is it true that AR uses more memory to generate _the same SQL code_? Could I conserve memory here and there by running `Model.where("id=10").first` instead of `Model.find(10)`; or `Model.where("age=50")` instead of `Model.where(age:50)`. Also, just to be sure I understand, when you say I shouldn't run `Model.all`, you mean it is bad practice to create a Ruby variable containing many AR objects; correct?

Comment: (1) Sure, AR will use more memory to generate `select * from t where ...` than just writing the SQL string itself but the difference isn't worth worry about. AR will be easier and less error prone here and the runtime cost will be vanishingly small. (2) The `where.first` and `find` ones will send pretty much the same SQL to the database and instantiate the same number of models so no real difference, use `find`. `where(string)` and `where(hash)` should be pretty much the same, use `where(hash)` when you can. (3) Right, `Model.all` creates too many model instances and that chews up memory.

Comment: Thank you. Follow-up, if you're game. I need to evaluate a few thousand Models and select one. The selection depends on how its attributes contribute to the cumulative attributes of a small collection of other Models. Currently, I start with an array of Models eligible to be added (bad! practice).  I narrow the array with a few queries. I haven't attempted to boil the 'narrowing' down to one query, though I could. Question: would it be better to start with an array of Model IDs and narrow down _that_? Like this `Food.select("id").where("age=50")` or `Food.where(age:50).pluck(:id)`.

Comment: If this warrants a new question or you are done helping for now, please let me know. @mu, forgot to tag you in the above comment (and ran out of characters).

Comment: A new question would make it easier to provide some details. If you only need the ids then 1k ids will take quite a bit less memory than 1k models. Generally it is best to push bulk/aggregate data operations into the database, databases are great at working with big piles of data.

Comment: Got it. I will try some things and then ask a new question if necessary. Thanks again @mu.